# Is there a way to create an instance of a generic type in Scala other than reflection

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am new to scala and after reading the scala tour I started working on a simple project to practice a bit.

In my project I wanted to extend the functionality of the Seq trait by making a implicit class that would wrap Seq and add some functionality on top.

My problem is something like this:

```scala
  implicit class wrapper[S[X] <: Seq[X], E](seq : S[E]) {
    def funkyFunc : S[S[E]] = {
      Seq[S[E]](seq)
    }
  }
```

This code won't compile because the compiler cant cast Seq[S[E]] to S[S[E]],
so I tried to use casting like this:

```scala
  implicit class wrapper[S[X] <: Seq[X], E](seq : S[E]) {
    def funkyFunc : S[S[E]] = {
      Seq[S[E]](seq).asInstanceOf[S[S[E]]]
    }
  }
```

But now I the problem is at run time, when I try to pass a type that extends from Seq but list cant be cast into him we will get an exception.

I can't create an instance of type S[S[E]] because Seq doesn't have a contractor.

So is there a solution that I am missing that will let me get a behavior like this one:

```scala
  implicit class wrapper[S[X] <: Seq[X], E](seq : S[E]) {
    def funkyFunc : S[S[E]] = {
      S[S[E]]() :+ seq
    }
  }
```

**Edit**:
I am using scala 2.13

Comment: If you are new to Scala this might not be the best place to start. It is probably better to get experience using the existing collection classes before trying to write your own.

Comment: If you decide to go this way you'll have to reinvent `CanBuildFrom`-like concepts which has fortunately been removed in scala-2.13. Implicits + subtiping + type inference will never work well together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
import scala.collection.Factory

implicit class wrapper[S[X] <: Seq[X], E](seq : S[E]) {
  def funkyFunc(implicit f: Factory[S[E], S[S[E]]]) : S[S[E]] = {
    Seq(seq).to(f)
  }
}

List(1, 2, 3).funkyFunc // List(List(1, 2, 3))
```

Comment: But from where will the funkyFunc get his Factory? if I want to use this method I'll need to create a function for each collection that I want to support multiplied by my implemented functions in my implicit class. This seems like a lot of work

Comment: @nhruo If you create new collection then surely you must implement its factory. This is written in manual https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/custom-collections.html

Comment: @nhruo You usually don't have to provide anything. Implicit `def`s like [`iterableFactory`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Set$.html#iterableFactory[A]:scala.collection.Factory[A,CC[A]]) will usually provide the `Factory` automatically for every concrete `E` and `S`. Try it out in the repl: `import collection.Factory; implicitly[Factory[Any, Seq[Any]]]` will give you something. `implicitly[Factory[String, Seq[Any]]]` will give you something else. Again, `implicitly[Factory[String, List[String]]]` will again be slightly different. Most combinations are already covered.

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin After a bit of tinkering around I figured out that I can run your example if my list is saved as a Seq type var myList : Seq[Int]= List(2,2,2). But when I try to cast it to list scala wont find the implicit class. I think scala is using the implicit iterableFactory from IterableFactory Object which should work for list as well, sorry for the question but I cant find what I am missing. **EDIT** : Its a bug in IntelliJ it dose compile

Comment: @Dmytro Mitin Your answer + `println (List(1,2,3).funkyFunc)` in main, This dose complie but IntelliJ says it won't compile

Comment: @nhruo Ah ok, IntelliJ is irrelevant.